# Does the pre ping feature in SqlAlchemy db pools automatically reconnect and send the SQL command in case the pre ping check fails?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, connection-pooling

I want some clarification on how the pre ping feature exactly works with SqlAlchemy db pools. Let's say I try to make a SQL query to my database with the db pool. If the db pool sends a pre ping to check the connection and the connection is broken, does it automatically handle this? By handling I mean that it reconnects and then sends the SQL query? Or do I have to handle this myself in my code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html#disconnect-handling-pessimistic), yes stale connections are handled transparently:

> The calling application does not need to be concerned about organizing operations to be able to recover from stale connections checked out from the pool.

... unless:

> If the database is still not available when “pre ping” runs, then the
> initial connect will fail and the error for failure to connect will be
> propagated normally. In the uncommon situation that the database is
> available for connections, but is not able to respond to a “ping”, the
> “pre_ping” will try up to three times before giving up, propagating
> the database error last received.